# Ошибка в React native команда gradlew clean

Tags: gradle, react-native

как исправить эту ошибку
C:\react-native-app\node_modules\react-native\template\android>gradlew clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\react-native-app\node_modules\react-native\template\and
  roid\settings.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'HelloWorld'.

> Could not read script 'C:\react-native-app\node_modules\react-native\te
> mplate\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.
> gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

C:\react-native-app\node_modules\react-native\template\android>

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: отредактировала, нужна помощь в исправлении ошибки